# Spring Boot 2 - method annotated with @async is not called asynchronous

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

maybe someone can help me.
Within my **SpringBoot** 2 Application I want to call a service **asynchronous**. I know, there are lot of posts which cover this issue and I read many of them attentive but unfortunately I'm stuck.

The affected service is initialized within a configuration class (annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableAsync`).
The service implements an Interface and the interesting interface method I'm talking about is  annotated with `@Async`. But as I've read in another post this shouldn't be a problem.

The bean initialization with the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class GlobalConfiguration {


   @Bean
    public DocumentMimetypeDetectionService getPermittedMimetypes() throws IOException {
        DocumentMimetypeDetectionServiceImpl detectionService = new DocumentMimetypeDetectionServiceImpl();
        detectionService.setPermittedDocumentMimetypes(permittedDocumentMimetypes().getObjectType()
                .cast(permittedDocumentMimetypes().getObject()));
        return detectionService;
    }


   @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ServiceAsync-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }    

}
```

The interface of DocumentMimetypeDetectionService:

```
public interface DocumentMimetypeDetectionService {

    @Async
    CompletableFuture<String> discoverDocumentMimetype(final InputStream aIs)
            throws DocumentMimetypeDetectionServiceException, IOException;
}
```

I created a test to inspect if the service is calling asynchronous.
Additional to that I include a

> Thread.sleep(1000)
>
> log.debug("current thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());

in the Service-Implementation Class (method discoverDocumentMimetype)  to test the async behavior.

My test class is annotated with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and @SpringBootTest.

And now the call of the service method:

```
   private void checkFiles(List<FileInfo> files) 
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, MasterindexValidationException {

        List<Mt> mtList = new ArrayList<>();
        files.forEach(f -> {
            try {
                Mt mt = new Mt(mimetypeDetectionService.discoverDocumentMimetype(f.getFileContainer().getContent()), f.getFileId());
                mtList.add(mt);
                
            } catch (DocumentMimetypeDetectionServiceException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("error in verifying mimetype of file %s - detail: %s", f.getFileId(), e.getMessage()));
            }
        });
```

What I observed:
The call of

> Mt mt = new Mt(mimetypeDetectionService.discoverDocumentMimetype(f.getFileContainer().getContent()), f.getFileId());

doesn't result in a asynchronous behavoir. Means, the document detection service allways stuck in the thread sleep and the Thread.Id ist always the same (log output).

What I'm doing wrong?
Any help are appreciate.
Many thanks in advance.

Regards, Bodo

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint in test and check whether the mimetypeDietectionService is proxy or a real class? In general if you've plugged everything right it should be a proxy... By Proxy I mean something that uses java.lang.Proxy or CGLIB in the class name - a class that has been created by spring on-the-fly during the startup.

Comment: `org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 1 interfaces [de.axa.services.ecm.contentmanagement.service.archivbearbeiten.services.DocumentMimetypeDetectionService]; 1 advisors [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor@6ef2f7ad]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [de.axa.services.ecm.contentmanagement.service.archivbearbeiten.services.DocumentMimetypeDetectionServiceImpl@1c10eb3a]]; proxyTargetClass=false; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false`   So, indeed it is a proxy.

Comment: But what does Mt() do? It looks to me like you are taking an asynchronous call and then forcing the content to be returned immediately, which means the calling code will have to wait for that asynchronous call to finish.

Comment: Hi Gimby, it does not depend on `Mt`. I already checked it. Mt is just a small pojo:   ` @AllArgsConstructor
    private class Mt {
        private CompletableFuture<String> currentMt;
        private String fileId;
    } `

Comment: Fair enough. It it important to add such proof to the question though.